# Self-hosted alternatives to VNC that don't require a static IP?

Tags: networking

I was trying to set up a VNC server on my parent's laptops, so that I could provide remote assistance. I logged in (via Chrome Remote Desktop), installed TightVNC and set up port forwarding on the router, but could not connect to it. After a bunch of googling around, I discovered that the issue was the ISP was not assigning them a static IP (router's WAN ip address was 172.17.xx.xx).

Is there anything I can self-host that will let me access their machine remotely? (That is, I want to install some sort of server on my own box, which does have a static ip, and then a client on their laptops that will let me log in remotely, along the lines of logmein/teamviewer/etc but self-hosted)

Comment: If you want to use a self-hosted solution, you will need to setup [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) at your parent place so that you can connect via Hostname. Some routers support Dynamic DNS out of the box, however if not, you will need to install something like [DuckDNS](https://www.duckdns.org/why.jsp) on a device at your parent house.

Comment: I don't think it's a DNS problem so much as the fact that they don't have an externally accessible IP address. (From what i can tell, the router showing a wan ip address in the 172.xx.xx.xx block means the ISP has implemented carrier-grade NAT). I need something like teamviewer or chrome remote desktop, which will let both machines connect via an external server.

Comment: You are correct, sorry I missed that part. If CGN is being used, anything that relies on Port Forwarding wont work. Perhaps it's time to look into VPN options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [VNC Repeater like this one](https://github.com/tomka/ultravnc-repeater/blob/master/ultravnc_repeater.pl). Here is an excerpt from [this excellent guide by *James B*](http://lightofdawn.org/wiki/wiki.cgi/Nat2NatVNC):

There are two ways to run a VNC proxy:

### First one is to use the so-called VNC repeater.

This technology was first developed by UltraVNC but it is now quite popular and available for many VNC derivatives.
[Here](http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-repeater.html) is an explanation from the horse's mouth of how it works. You want to use mode 2 as that's the mode that enables both server and clients to be behind NATs.

You can download the repeater software from UltraVNC website itself; but unless you're planning to use Windows on the repeater OS, I'd recommend you get them from somewhere else because they are updated more often.

The repeater software comes into flavours: a C source code that you need to compile and build yourself (preferably on the proxy machine; or at least on the machine that runs on the same OS as the proxy machine); and a Perl script that you can just run as is. Both require that you run them as daemons (that is, server process) on the proxy machine; continuously listening for connections from both servers and clients.

In either case, please note that for this to work, you will need that both VNC client and server supports UltraVNC repeater extension. Standard server and client will not work. And example of VNC client that will work with these repeaters is [SSVNC](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ssvnc.html).

The Perl script version is available [here](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html#faq-firewall-out). Look for a file called ultravnc_repeater.pl (or you can download the file directly from [this link](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ultravnc_repeater.pl)). I have tested this script and it works beautifully.

The C source code version is available [here](http://koti.mbnet.fi/jtko/). It was a port of the original UltraVNC repeater version (which was Windows-only) so it is more or less is the "official" version.

There are other unofficial versions too:

```
http://code.google.com/p/uvncrepeater
https://code.google.com/p/vncrepeater
```

I have not tested any of the C version, so I can't comment on their usability. The last link is especially interesting because it claims to work with standard VNC clients instead of UltraVNC-extended client.

Once the proxy server is setup, to initiate connection to the proxy, on server side:

```
x11vnc -connect repeater=ID:1234+host:port
```

where "1234" is a unique ID that identifies this server to the repeater.

On the client side:

```
ssvncviewer -repeater ID:1234 host:port
```

The client uses the same ID so that the repeater can connect it to the correct server.

The host:port on both server and client refers to the proxy server. The ports are not the same; usually the server port is 5500 and the client port is 5900. x11vnc and ssvnc is used in this example but you can easily use other UltraVNC-compatible server and clients.

### Another option is to run VNC Transferer

The VNC connector is a relatively newer invention that the repeater. It enables standard server and client to connect to each other. From usage point of view it works similarly to the repeater but internally it works differently.

The software is available as a CGI Perl script courtesy or Karl Runge (the author of both ssvnc and ultra_repeater Perl script), here: [vncxfer](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/vncxfer).

To use this, you need to have a web server running on the proxy server and configure it to run vncxfer script as CGI. When connected, the script will create a server process that will handle both server and client connections. The server process will create dynamically-allocated ephemeral port pair; one for the server and one for the client.

Connection is initiated by accessing the CGI URL using a web browser. The web page you see will ask for a "session id"; once that given it will launch a session with a random port for the server and the client. You must initiate both client and server connection within a given time (by default is 300 seconds) or the session will be cancelled.

Launch VNC server to connect to proxy using -connect as usual (no ID is required):

```
x11vnc -connect host:port
```

and launch the client as usual (no -repeater string is required)

```
vncviewer host:port
```

The host:port on both server and client refers to the proxy server. The ports are not the same; the webpage will tell you which port is for the server and which port is for the client. x11vnc is used in this example but you can easily use other server and clients.

Once the connection is ended, vncxfer will terminate the ephemeral session.

Note: you can't run this on ordinary webhosting account. You need VPS account because:

1. Ordinary webhosting account usually forbids a long-running process in response to a CGI call (the vncxfer server process is effectively that)
2. Ordinary webhosting account usually don't allow access to arbitrary ports other than HTTP and HTTPS (or SMTP).